# How to display server side errors in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

Could someone tell me why this method call in meteor.js v1.3 isn't outputting any console.logs to my terminal when it is running? This method works great in a different meteor project when I wasn't using the validatedmethod, and the Emails.insert function works but when I add the HTTP.post function, it fails but I can't figure out how to display the error because both `console.log(error)` and `Meteor.throw(error)` don't display anything in my server terminal. Thanks!

```
import { Emails } from './emails';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';
import { ValidatedMethod } from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';

export const insertEmail = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'emails.insert',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    email: { type: String }
  }).validator(),
  run(email) {
    let isPresent = Emails.find({email: email.email}).fetch();

    if(isPresent < 1){
      Emails.insert({email: email.email, ip: '1'});

      HTTP.post('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer "+Meteor.settings.private.sendGridMarketingKey,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        content: '[{\"email\": \"'+email+'\"}]'
      },function( error, response ) {
        if ( error ) {
          throw new Meteor.Error(500, error);
          console.log( error );
        } else {
          throw new Meteor.Error(500, response);
          console.log( response );
        }
      });



    } else {
      throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'This Email is Already Added!')
    }



  },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`throw` exits the function in Javascript. Put your `console.log` before the `throw`.